# Putting method implementations of the same class in different object files

Tags: c++, linker

I'm working on a big project in C++.

I have many classes which have methods that do completely different things (like one dumps, another modifies the object, another checks it to see if it's valid and so on...).

Is it a good style to put the implementation of a method for all the classes in a source file (or in a group of object files that may be archived) and all of the implementations of another method of the classes in another archive?

Could this be good when linking, maybe when someone doesn't need the dumping methods (for example), or it's better to keep the method implementations of the same class in the same source file, in order to not make confusion?

Comment: Every class is declared in an header which has to do with the class itself. Then in the associated source file there are implementations of methods that have to do with the object itself (as you said, getters, setters, ctors/dtors...). Then other methods (which are overridden in almost the whole class hierarchy) are implemented in a completely separated part of the project.

Comment: If you create archive from object files, linker will select only those object files that are needed, but note that if it'll decide to select some object file, the whole object file will be included, not only part that is needed, so I think it's better to separate functionality in multiple object files and then create archive from them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are trade-offs.

When you change the implementation of any function, the entire translation unit must be re-compiled into a new object file.

If you write only a single function per translation unit, you minimize the length of compilation time caused by unnecessary rebuilds.

On the other hand, writing a single function per translation unit, you maximize the length of compilation time from scratch, because it's slower to compile many small TU's than a few bit TU's.

The optimal solution is personal preference, but usually somewhere in between "single function per TU" and "one massive TU for entire program" (rather than exactly one of those). For member functions, one TU per class is a popular heuristic, but not necessarily always the best choice.

---

Another consideration is optimisation. Calls to non-inline functions can be expanded inline, but only within the same translation unit. Therefore, it is easier for the compiler to optimize a single massive TU.

Of course, you can choose to define the functions inline, in the header file, but that causes a re-building problem, because if any of the inline functions change, then all who include the header must re-build. This is worse problem than simply having bigger TUs but not as bad as having one massive TU.

So, defining related non-inline functions within the same TU allows the compiler to decide on optimization within that TU, while preventing a re-build cascade. This is advantageous if those related functions would benefit from inline expansion and call each other a lot.

This advantage is mitigated by *whole program optimisation*.

---

Third consideration is organisation. It may be likely, that a programmer who looks at member function of a class would also be interested in other member functions of that class. Having them in the same source file will allow them to spend less time on searching the correct file.

The organizational advantage of grouping all class functions into a common source file is somewhat mitigated by modern IDEs that allow for quickly jumping from source file to header and from there to the other function.

---

Fourth consideration is the performance of the editor. Parsing a file of tens of thousands of lines or more can be slow and may use a lot of memory depending on parsing technique. One massive TU doesn't necessarily cause this, because you can use separate files that are only included together.

On the other hand, massive number of files can be problematic for some file browsers (probably not much these days) and also for version control systems.

---

Finally, my opinion: I think that one source file per class is a decent heuristic. But it should not be followed religiously when it's not appropriate.

Comment: Yes! The question was more about the project management in general than about the compilation efficiency. Since the functions will not change that often, a massive TU is better in terms of compilation speed in my case.

Comment: @osnapitzkindle if the functions do not change, then you don't need to compile at all. If a single function changes, then massive TU will cause the entire program to rebuild and single function pre TU will allow only that one function to be recompiled. I've arrived at the opposite conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Some organizations have rules that mandate one definition per unit. In these organizations, a header file can define only one class, and a translation unit can define only one function. Other organizations mandate at most one source file for each header files (some header files have no implementation).

The optimal thing to do is somewhere in between. I generally don't care about compiler or linker performance. I do care a lot about code readability and maintainability. A source file that implements some class that is thousands of lines long is hard to navigate. It's better to break that file into multiple files. Breaking it into hundreds of files, one file per function, makes for a directory structure that is difficult to navigate. Breaking it into chunks of closely related functions keeps the directory structure and the contents of each file navigable.

However, and this is a big however: Why is your class so large that you have to worry about this? A class whose implementation spans thousands of lines or dozens of files is a code smell.